# How to allow PHP file to be only accessible through call reference /view.php?url=123

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to block direct access to my php file and make it work only through a call reference like:
 mysite.com/view.php?**url=123**
And when it is called direct: mysite.com/**view.php**
Returns: Invalid ID!

My script:

```
if(isset($_GET['url']) && isset($sources[$_GET['url']])){
$link = $sources[$_GET['url']]; }
```

Comment: `if(url not set or empty or not found){die('invalid id')}`

Comment: How can I insert this on my code? Sorry I'm starting in php.

Comment: `if(!isset($_GET['url']) && intval($_GET['url']) <= 0){ echo "Invalid ID";exit; }`

Comment: if(isset($_GET['url']) && isset($sources[$_GET['url']])){
$link = $sources[$_GET['url']]; } else{ echo "invalid ID";exit;}

Comment: Post as answer then I mark your answer as right!

Comment: posted as answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update in question, you just need to add ELSE condition, if condition false than execute else part, something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['url']) && isset($sources[$_GET['url']])){
   $link = $sources[$_GET['url']]; 
}
else{
   echo "Invalid ID"; // error message
}
```

But, in your IF condition, you have a problem, suppose if any one try to access this URL:

```
mysite.com/view.php?url=asdfasdf
```

Maybe, you code break, in this case, you can also use `intval()` function, **if value of url always integer.**

Comment: Where do I insert he intval()?

Comment: if value of URL, always integer than you can use, if value of url, mix than no need. @asdaqwr14241adadad214fvagsdg

Comment: Forgot you code? You did this first: else { echo "Invalid ID";exit;}

Comment: @asdaqwr14241adadad214fvagsdg: it means, your rest code is execute, u can use exit.

Comment: @asdaqwr14241adadad214fvagsdg: yes, test it

Comment: Other question, how can I show an image instead of Invalid ID? Thanks for your support brother... It's working fine, I'll be using it anyway.

Comment: `echo "<img src='imagepath'>";` @asdaqwr14241adadad214fvagsdg

Comment: Thank you so much! You rocks! :D

Comment: @asdaqwr14241adadad214fvagsdg: glad to help u bro

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
if(!$url) {
    die('Invalid ID!');
}
```

Comment: this will break: `view.php?url=asdasdasdasd`

Comment: why this will break - this should be fine. You didn't say that url should be int string or whatever. If this will be an int then the url name is wrong - it should called simply: id